# Would like to align JPanel to LEFT side of a frame in Java

Tags: java, swing, jlabel

This is turning out to be much more difficult than I would have assumed. All I want to do is "stick" this JPanel to the left side of the frame. Here's what I have so far. (I don't want to use a GridBagLayout if possible (I am a java novice)).

```
labels = new JPanel();
JLabel currentWordLA = new JLabel("Current word:");
JLabel triedLettersLA = new JLabel("Tried letters:");
JLabel triesLeftLA = new JLabel("Tries remaining:");
JButton restart = new JButton("Reset");

labels.setLayout(new BoxLayout(labels, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
labels.add(currentWordLA);
labels.add(triedLettersLA);
labels.add(triesLeftLA);
scorePanel.add(labels, BorderLayout.WEST);
```

Edit: Sorry guys, here's the full code. It's sort of a panel within a panel within a frame. Just trying to get the frame to be aligned to the left. Thanks!

```
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Hangman {

    JFrame frame;
    private String[] wordList = {
        "computer", "java", "activity", "alaska", "appearance", "article",
        "automobile", "basket", "birthday", "canada", "central", "character",
        "chicken", "chosen", "cutting", "daily", "darkness", "diagram",
        "disappear", "driving", "effort", "establish", "exact",
        "establishment", "fifteen", "football", "foreign", "frequently",
        "frighten", "function", "gradually", "hurried", "identity",
        "importance", "impossible", "invented", "italian", "journey",
        "lincoln", "london", "massage", "minerals", "outer", "paint",
        "particles", "personal", "physical", "progress", "quarter",
        "recognise", "replace", "rhythm", "situation", "slightly",
        "steady", "stepped", "strike", "successful", "sudden",
        "terrible", "traffic", "unusual", "volume", "yesterday"};
    private String mysteryWord;
    private boolean finished = false;
    private boolean won = false;
    private Button a[];

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Hangman gui = new Hangman();
        gui.go();
    }

    class myDrawPanel extends JPanel {

        public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            setBackground(Color.white);
            g.setColor(Color.gray);
            g.fillRect(50, 200, 150, 20);
            g.fillRect(90, 20, 10, 200);
            g.fillRect(90, 20, 60, 10);
            g.setColor(Color.black);
            g.fillRect(145, 20, 5, 25);
        }
    }

    public void go() {
        frame = new JFrame("Hangman");
        JPanel topPanel = new JPanel();
        myDrawPanel noosePanel = new myDrawPanel();
        JPanel bottomPanel = new JPanel();
        JPanel scorePanel = new JPanel();

        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setLayout(new GridLayout(2, 0));
        bottomPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(0, 2));
        scorePanel.setSize(20, 100);

        noosePanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Your progress."));
        topPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Your arsenal."));
        scorePanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Your score."));
        frame.add(topPanel);
        frame.add(bottomPanel);
        bottomPanel.add(scorePanel);
        bottomPanel.add(noosePanel);

        //The Stats section.
        JPanel labels = new JPanel();
        JLabel currentWordLA = new JLabel("Current word:");
        JLabel triedLettersLA = new JLabel("Tried letters:");
        JLabel triesLeftLA = new JLabel("Tries remaining:");
        JButton restart = new JButton("Reset");

        labels.setLayout(new BoxLayout(labels, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
        labels.add(currentWordLA);
        labels.add(triedLettersLA);
        labels.add(triesLeftLA);
        scorePanel.add(labels, BorderLayout.WEST);

        int i;
        StringBuffer buffer;
        a = new Button[26];
        topPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(4, 0, 10, 10));

        // create all 26 buttons
        for (i = 0; i < 26; i++) {
            buffer = new StringBuffer();
            buffer.append((char) (i + 65));
            a[i] = new Button(buffer.toString());
            a[i].setSize(100, 100);
            //a[i].addActionListener( this );
            topPanel.add(a[i]);
        }

        frame.setSize(500, 500);
        frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: Is that all you have until now? For `BorderLayout` to work correctly, you need to add more components to the panel.

Comment: you could implement a constructor, instead of 'go()'.

Answer (score 2):

try adding something to BorderLayout.CENTER, like this:

```
    scorepanel.add(new JPanel(), BorderLayout.CENTER); //I guess scorepanel is your frame
    //your code here
```

Answer (score 2):

I like your layout. I made some changes to your example:

- It looks like `MyDrawPanel` is just for drawing. If you override `getPreferredSize`, you can use `pack()` instead of calling `setSize()` a lot. Inside `paintComponent`, do your drawing relative to the panel's `getWidth` and `getHeight`, then it'll look right for any size.
- I used `JLabel.LEFT` for the labels, and I made the background color gray so you can see where the layout is. There's more [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/box.html).
- If you use standard naming, like `MyDrawPanel`, it'll be easier for other people to read your code.

Code:

```
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Hangman {

    JFrame frame;
    private String[] wordList = {
        "computer", "java", "activity", "alaska", "appearance", "article",
        "automobile", "basket", "birthday", "canada", "central", "character",
        "chicken", "chosen", "cutting", "daily", "darkness", "diagram",
        "disappear", "driving", "effort", "establish", "exact",
        "establishment", "fifteen", "football", "foreign", "frequently",
        "frighten", "function", "gradually", "hurried", "identity",
        "importance", "impossible", "invented", "italian", "journey",
        "lincoln", "london", "massage", "minerals", "outer", "paint",
        "particles", "personal", "physical", "progress", "quarter",
        "recognise", "replace", "rhythm", "situation", "slightly",
        "steady", "stepped", "strike", "successful", "sudden",
        "terrible", "traffic", "unusual", "volume", "yesterday"};
    private String mysteryWord;
    private boolean finished = false;
    private boolean won = false;
    private Button a[];

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Hangman gui = new Hangman();
        gui.go();
    }

    class MyDrawPanel extends JPanel {

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(256, 256);
        }

        @Override
        public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            setBackground(Color.white);
            g.setColor(Color.gray);
            g.fillRect(50, 200, 150, 20);
            g.fillRect(90, 20, 10, 200);
            g.fillRect(90, 20, 60, 10);
            g.setColor(Color.black);
            g.fillRect(145, 20, 5, 25);
        }
    }

    public void go() {
        frame = new JFrame("Hangman");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setLayout(new GridLayout(2, 0));

        JPanel topPanel = new JPanel();
        topPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Your arsenal."));
        MyDrawPanel noosePanel = new MyDrawPanel();
        noosePanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Your progress."));
        JPanel bottomPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0, 2));
        JPanel scorePanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout());
        scorePanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Your score."));

        frame.add(topPanel);
        frame.add(bottomPanel);
        bottomPanel.add(scorePanel);
        bottomPanel.add(noosePanel);

        //The Stats section.
        JPanel labels = new JPanel();
        labels.setLayout(new BoxLayout(labels, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
        labels.setBackground(Color.lightGray);
        JLabel currentWordLA = new JLabel("Current word:", JLabel.LEFT);
        JLabel triedLettersLA = new JLabel("Tried letters:", JLabel.LEFT);
        JLabel triesLeftLA = new JLabel("Tries remaining:", JLabel.LEFT);

        labels.add(currentWordLA);
        labels.add(triedLettersLA);
        labels.add(triesLeftLA);
        scorePanel.add(labels);

        int i;
        StringBuffer buffer;
        a = new Button[26];
        topPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(4, 0, 10, 10));

        // create all 26 buttons
        for (i = 0; i < 26; i++) {
            buffer = new StringBuffer();
            buffer.append((char) (i + 65));
            a[i] = new Button(buffer.toString());
            //a[i].addActionListener( this );
            topPanel.add(a[i]);
        }
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```